# Unable to load data in Netezza from excel source using SSIS fast Load option

Tags: excel, ssis, netezza

I am using SSIS(Fast Load option) to import data into Netezza from excel source. The package is running fine but I could not see any data inserted into the destination table. The number of columns and column order differs in source file and table. Is there any fix for this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the mapping and verify that you have to un-check the over write option